# Show EditViewController while editing, show DetailViewController when not editing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I do have a UITableViewController which can be edited. 
I do have 2 Segues in my Storyboard, coming from the tableView going to an EditViewController (via modal) and the second one via Push to the DetailViewController.

I want, when the tableview isEditing, that the segue to editviewcontroller is executed, and when is not editing, than to DetailViewController.

I tried different ways, with the prepareforsegue method. then several tries with the didselectrowatindexpath method, where I stand now.

Now, when the tableView is in editing and I touch one cell, the detailviewcontroller pushes and on top of this the editviewcontroller comes in as modal view controller.

Here is my code. 
Can you please give me hints:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath %i", indexPath.row);
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (tableView.isEditing == FALSE) {
    NSLog(@"isediting");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:cell];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showEditPerson" sender:cell];
}
}
```

and here is what i have tried with the prepare for segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *theChild = [myAppDelegate.myPersonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:theChild];
}
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showEditPerson"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *theChild = [myAppDelegate.myPersonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:theChild];
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you still have the segue hooked up to the prototype cell in the Storyboard file? Try putting breakpoints in prepareForSegue to see where it gets triggered from.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks a lot. You are right. I hooked up the TableViewCell to the DetailViewController and not the RoottableView to the DetailViewController. Thanks again! Yours, Raphael

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above:

It seems you have the prototype cell hooked up to a segue in addition to the delegate method. Fix the segue connections and you should be all set.